# Solace VMR Installation through Command Line using virtual-install

Tags: libvirt, solace

I am trying to install solacevmr on centOS 7 through command line. The solace docs give a guide to install solaceVMR through GUI only - [Guide](http://docs.solace.com/Solace-VMR-Set-Up/Starting-VMRs-for-the-First-Time/Setting-Up-a-VMR-with-KVM-on-CentOS.htm)

The command I am using is:

```
virt-install --name solacekvm --ram 4096 --cpu host --arch x86_64 --vcpu 2 --virt-type qemu --disk path={path to cow image}  --force --network bridge:virbr0 --connect qemu:///system --nographics --import
```

But I am not sure if this the correct command to execute; and on executing this command I get the following error logs in virt-viewer console.

[The error trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdz5U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your virt-install command is valid.

The error trace indicates that the VM instance is unable to mount the file system. Please verify that the qcow2 image that you've downloaded is not corrupt.

The md5sum of `soltr-8.0.0.102-vmr-evaluation.qcow2.xz` is `c1afcb8ced0c6ecadd4d0ebec521486d`.
The md5sums of other VMR variants can be found over at http://dev.solace.com/downloads/